# Best way to remove unknown characters and spaces using C#?

Tags: c#

Unknown Characters:

|b9-12-2016,¢Xocoak¡LO2A35(2)(b)¡ÓocORe3ao-i|],¢Xa?u¡±o¡±i?¢X$3,597,669On 9-12-2016, the price adjusted to $3,597,669 dueto the reason allowed under section 35(2)(b) of theOrdinance

Good Result:

$3,597,669On 9-12-2016, the price adjusted to $3,597,669 due to the reason allowed under section 35 of the Ordinance

Comment: Is this a standard pattern?

Comment: yes, do you have idea brother?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use regular expressions to do this. You can use the `Regex.Replace` method to run regular expressions on your text. Regular expressions are patterns that a regular expression engine tries to match in input text. I recommend that you take a look at the MSDN article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also take a look at the documentation for the `Regex.Replace` method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, in order to remove the letter c you could use this snippet of code:

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, "c", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This would replace both lowercase and capital Cs because the ignore case option is turned on.

Comment: thanks you are nice!

Comment: @StephenShuane thank you if you found my answer helpful please mark it as accepted.

Comment: how can I accept? I am newly in stockoverflow.

Comment: @StephenShuane there's a tick on the left, below the downvote. click that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a standard pattern as what you've told me. Use the following code. It takes everything after the last `$` sign.

```
    string str = "|b9-12-2016,¢Xocoak¡LO2A35(2)(b)¡ÓocORe3ao-i|],¢Xa?u¡±o¡±i?¢X$3,597,669On 9-12-2016, the price adjusted to $3,597,669 dueto the reason allowed under section 35(2)(b) of theOrdinance";
    var result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('$'));
```